# how to show and hide columns of using datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to show and hide the columns of the datatable after doing a javascript test, but it doesn't work good.

This is my test javascript:

```
if ( $('#commune_to_display').val()==""){
    $('#utable td:nth-child(2)').hide();
    $('#commune_to ').hide();
}
```

This test works just in the first page of the datatable, after pagination the column is still visible.

How can I fix it? thanks for help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can show/hide columns as shown below. Just replace `3` and `4` with your actual column indexes.

```
var table = $('#utable').DataTable();
table.column(3).visible(true);    // To show
table.column(4).visible(false);   // To hide
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

html code like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

You can view and run the full example here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html